# Why does a higher temperature increase absorption / optical density?

Tags: optics, atomic-physics, quantum-optics, molecules

Suppose we have for example a gas of bimolecular iodine. Suppose we shine ultraviolet laser light on it.
Then the absorption of ultraviolet increases when we increase the temperature. From what I read it is caused by "hot bands" which is nothing else than thermal excitation of electrons. But why does this increase the absorption of the light? I would be happy about a detailed reasoning!

Here is an example for data that I took (OD = optical density):

[image]

Comment: See the **much** better (much higher resolution) spectrum here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/161739/79678 and follow the [link](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Physical_Chemistry_(LibreTexts)/13%3A_Molecular_Spectroscopy/13.06%3A_Electronic_Spectra_Contain_Electronic_Vibrational_and_Rotational_Information) for a discussion of the hot bands in iodine.

Comment: The spectra you give are at temperatures below iodine’s melting point and above its boiling point. The vapor pressure at the higher temperature is higher than at the lower temperature, so the vapor phase number density (“concentration”) of absorbing species is higher and, hence, there is higher absorbance in the leftmost band.

Comment: Thanks, could you briefly elaborate on why exactly there is more absorption in vapor phase? Thanks!

Comment: It is just number density. If you put solid iodine in a glass bottle with the lid on, there are iodine molecules in the headspace. These can easily be detected by opening the bottle and taking a whiff. Or you can use laser-induced fluorescence: I can provide a literature reference on that, by Prof. Emeritus Joel Tellinghuisen of Vanderbilt University, if you wish. He is an expert of iodine vapor spectroscopy. Put solid iodine is a test tube, heat it up, and you see the violet colored vapor. The (reasonably) higher the temperature, the more optically dense the vapor is.

Comment: Oh, I see the lower number density argument! Thanks!! But doesn't also the excitation of states also matter? If yes, how?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking about, e.g., what was the relevance of the ultraviolet light mentioned in your 2nd and 3rd sentences? In any event, iodine spectroscopy is complicated and I am not expert on it. But Prof. Tellinghuisen is, so [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4757/79678) is a list of some (not all) of his iodine spectroscopy publications as of 2018. As for your question, higher temperature means both increased vapor phase number density and also increased populations in the vibrational levels.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I read it is caused by "hot bands" which is nothing else than thermal excitation of electrons.

I do not know if the answer will be detailed enough, but I will try to solve the issue about this quote.

It is not "simply" thermal excitations of electrons. What happens is the creation of a new possible energy transition between excited states.

To be more clear: In the ground states you have a given number of possible excitations/transitions, if you heat up the system you create different excited states, and thus you can have transitions between them.
This results in a stronger absorption due to the fact that there is a greater chance to excite this transitions.

Comment: Please see the comment I left for the OP.

Comment: Okay, eventually the referenced article refers to this article: 

https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Physical_Chemistry_(LibreTexts)/13%3A_Molecular_Spectroscopy/13.06%3A_Electronic_Spectra_Contain_Electronic_Vibrational_and_Rotational_Information

According to this, the rise in temperature creates additional absorption bands, but shifted in wavelength (there they are called v' and v''). However, in my data even the leftmost part is shifted upwards!

Comment: "If the sample is hot, then excited vibrational levels of the ground state may be populated, and these also will absorb light."

It is exactly what I wrote in my answer, in a concise way...

Comment: Right, but in the image https://chem.libretexts.org/@api/deki/files/125628/i2uvvis.gif?revision=1 these bands are the middle one v' and the right one v''. These are the bands you were talking about I think. But in my data, the absorption is also significantly increased at the left (500-550 nm). Where does this come from?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to solve the issue about the possible transition present in the system when you "alter" the ground state.
But....
"The vibrational-electronic spectrum of I2 in the region from 500-650 nm displays a large number of well-defined bands which, for the most part, correspond to v'<-- 0 transitions..."

I believe the reference given by Ed V explains a bit of everything.

In general, whenever you change T you'll affect the electron behavior both from possible transitions and the "agitation" that makes the medium more opaque